# Checkbox Uncheck Event Handler in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Basically I am trying to detect if the checkbox is checked then perform some functions in JavaScript. Here is how I set up my checkbox:

```
 var content = "<table class=\"filter-table\">";
 content += "<tr><td><label><input class=\"moh_SC\"  type=\"checkbox\" id=\"cb_sc\" onclick=\"toggleOverlayer('moh_SC')\" checked='checked'>Service Coverage</label></td></tr>" +
           "<tr><td><div id=\"moh_SC\"></div></td></tr>";

 content += "<tr><td><label><input class=\"moh_HDD\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick=\"toggleOverlayer('moh_HDD')\">HDB DU Density</label></td></tr>" +
           "<tr><td><div id=\"moh_HDD\"></div></td></tr>";

 content += "</table>"
```

The onclick toggleOverlayer basically just switching the map layer by passing in an ID and form a query.

If the first checkbox is checked, the minimized window should be maximized. It should be minimize again when it is unchecked. So, I came up with these codes:

```
if($('#cb_sc').is(':checked'))
{
displayPSC();
maximise_poly_coverage_info_box();
}else 
{
minimise_poly_coverage_info_box();
}
```

When I first load the page, it is maximized which is correct because my first checkbox was set to checked by default. But when I uncheck the first checkbox, it does not execute the minimized function. I wonder how to do in a way like: when checkbox is unchecked, then perform some function either by jQuery or JavaScript.

**PS** I cannot change the toggleOverlayer() as it might affect all my other layers.

Thanks in advance.

**Worked Version**

```
//Maximized the window when first load cause the first checkbox is checked by default
           displayPSC();
           maximise_poly_coverage_info_box();

           //Checkbox event delegation
           $( "#cb_sc" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
               if($('#cb_sc').is(':checked'))
               {
                   displayPSC();
                   maximise_poly_coverage_info_box();
               }else 
               {
                   minimise_poly_coverage_info_box();
               }
           });
```

Comment: Please Provide a fiddle. OR try it - http://jsfiddle.net/Nba89/89/

Comment: How you are bind event is important? Show us that code

Comment: Forgive me that I cannot because it was too messy as all the functions were keep adding on by previous patches

Comment: My toggleOverlayer() basically just take in ID and switch the map layer. See edited

Comment: @Newbie, just starting few lines would be helpful than complete guess? I guess you need [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: @Satpal Sure thing, I managed to do it with event delegation. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Newbie, Post whatever worked for you as an answer that will help others in future.